# What is the difference between iterable and Subscriptable? Are there any objects which fall into just one of these object types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, types, iterable

What is the **difference between subscriptable and iterable** objects ?
What are the objects which are subscriptable but not iterable and vice versa?

P.s. Subscriptable are objects which contains other objects in it and iterators are subscriptable which can be iterated. But nothing more than this i can think of.

Comment: Iterables can be *iterated* with `for .. in ..`. Subscripts are `a[b]`. Those two are obviously different, and while often related, they don't have to be…?!

Comment: Sure. Just one example: a `set` object is iterable, but it is not subscriptable.

Comment: "P.s. Subscriptable are objects which contains other objects in it and iterators are subscriptable which can be iterated." No, not exactly. *Subscriptable* objects are objects that implement `__getitem__`. Iterable objects implement `__iter__`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the difference between subscriptable and iterable objects ?

- subscriptable objects implement [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) and thus the evaluation of the `obj[key]` syntax.
- iterable objects implement [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) and thus support iteration.

> What are the objects which are subscriptable but not iterable

An example is [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.__getitem__) which returns a subscriptable that is not iterable.

```
import re
m = re.match(r"\w+ (\w+)", "Isaac Newton, physicist")
```

You then *can* do:

```
print(m[1])  # "Newton"
```

but this produces an exception:

```
for word in m:  # TypeError: 're.Match' object is not iterable
    print(word)
```

> and vice versa?

An example is a `set`, which supports iteration but not subscription. So you *can* do:

```
for x in set([42]):
    print(x)  # 42
```

...but this produces an error:

```
set([42])[0]  # TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by @juanpa.arrivillaga in his comment:

> Subscriptable objects are objects that implement `__getitem__`. Iterable objects implement `__iter__`

so *at the language level* those concepts are not directly related

That being said, most common *containers* like lists or dictionnaries are both iterables and subscriptables. But a `set` is an example of iterable and non subscriptable container, and the same, generators produce iterable and non subscriptable objects.

I have no common example for a substriptable but non iterable object, but it is easy to imagine a special class verifying that. The corner case is that if the subscripts can be integers, the object will not be a true iterable (cannot use `iter` on it), but the `for ... in ...` will still work by under the hood reverting to calling `__getitem__` on successive integers

But here is a possible example (even if I cannot imagine a real world use case for that):

```
class SubscriptNonIter:
    def __init__(self, count):
        self._count = count
        
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return ''.join(c for i, c in enumerate(key) if i % self._count == 0)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> x = SubscriptNonIter(2)
>>> x['abcd']
'ac'
>>> for i in x:
    print(i)

    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 1, in <module>
    for i in x:
  File "...", line 6, in __getitem__
    return ''.join(c for i, c in enumerate(key) if i % self._count == 0)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```